# how do I bypass microsoft nuget?

Tags: .net, nuget

If I want to avoid using the Microsoft NuGet, how do I get the stuff that the NuGet would suck into my machine?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the whole point of using NuGet?

Comment: Who says you have to use it in the first place ? If you don't want to - for whatever reason - you don't.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the 3rd party library maker's site and download it yourself.

Comment: Or, if they only distribute their stuff as a NuGet package, [download the NuGet package directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14895173/33080)

Answer (score 3):

Find out however it was distributed before NuGet was around, and see if they still provide that mechanism.

There's no general answer, because different projects distribute their stuff in different ways.

Update: Since it appears that you're trying to avoid the NuGet executable code rather than the NuGet infrastructure, you could look at the source of NuGet itself, at http://nuget.codeplex.com/ to see how it works.  I have a feeling it's built as a 'core' class library and then has thin wrappers around that to invoke its functions, so you might be able to reuse the core with your own wrapper.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there's no simple way of downloading stuff. (a) Is there a central store of so-called packages? If there is, what's its url? (b) I understand that a so-called package must be accompanied by a .nuspec file. Where are .nuspec files stored? Do they have urls?

Comment: So you want to download the nuget package, but just not with the NuGet code?  Nuget talks to a XML service on http://packages.nuget.org, but I don't know any more than that.