# How to download a Nuget package without nuget.exe or Visual Studio extension?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

How can I download a NuGet package? I don't have the NuGet Visual Studio extension or the command line program nuget.exe. How can I download the .nupack file from the web? As I understand I will be able to extract the `.dll` files from it (with 7-zip) to use as normal.

The package I happen to be interested in is http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async, but I would like to know how to do this *generally*.

In the world of Ruby this would be easy - every package page on the RubyGems website has a download link to a .gem file, e.g.: https://rubygems.org/gems/pony

---

The argument over NuGet's manifest destiny belongs elsewhere. It doesn't matter to this question why I eschew it. [I'm not the only one though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys3ja.png).

Comment: @JonSkeet: My development system is not connected to the internet (for security reasons) except by using a Windows Terminal Server session. This WTS does allow downloads, but I cannot start executeables, so there is no (convenient) way for me to get stuff that's only available via nuget (at least whilst at work, anyway).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Although building the URL or using tools is still possible, it is not needed anymore.

**https://www.nuget.org/ currently has a download link named "Download package"**, that is available even if you don't have an account on the site.

(at the bottom of the right column).

---

Example of EntityFramework's detail page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/:
(*Updated after comment of kwitee.*)

[image: Example of EntityFramework's detail page]

Comment: FYI, you can definitely use 7-zip to extract and it'll handle .nupkg filetype, but since they are just .zip files under the hood, you can also just change the extension to .zip and browse/unzip as needed.

Comment: Just be aware that you'll have to download any dependent packages manually if you go this route.

Comment: Or else trigger "nuget install" and look for URL used in verbose mode...

Answer (score 226):

Either make an account on the Nuget.org website, then log in, browse to the package you want and click on the **Download** link on the left menu.

---

Or guess the URL. They have the following format:

```
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{packageID}/{packageVersion}
```

Then simply unzip the .nupkg file and extract the contents you need.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, that worked. For the library I wanted it was https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.14-rc

Comment: If you just want the latest package, simply leave the `/{packageVersion}` part out.

Comment: @Muds You'll have to parse the nuspec and download the listed dependences yourself.

Comment: This answer still works, but is outdated. See below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32681762/2642204

Comment: How to download package dependencies?

Answer (score 35):

Based on [Xavier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895173/1501497), I wrote a Google chrome extension [NuTake](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutake/ibhhbcaipjilldjkhhblhgdedjgoecap?hl=en&gl=GB) to add links to the Nuget.org package pages.

Answer (score 12):

To obtain the current stable version of the NuGet package use:

```
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{packageID}
```

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like NuGet Package Explorer should be able to do it:

https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer

[image: NuGet Package Explorer]

(or like Colonel Panic says, 7-zip should probably do it)

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Just use the `"Open from Feed..."` option.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to http://www.nuget.org
2. Search for desired package. For example: Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
3. Download the package by clicking the Download link on the left.
4. Do step 3 for the dependencies which are not already installed.
   [image: Nuget download page]
5. Store all downloaded packages in a custom folder. The default is c:\Package source.
6. Open Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio and make sure you have an "Available package source" that points to the specified address in step 5; If not, simply add one by providing a custom name and address. Click OK.
   [image: Tools->Manage NuGet Packages->Package Manager Settings]
   [image: NuGet Package Manager Options Window]
7. At this point you should be able to install the package exactly the same way you would install an online package **through the interface**. You probably won't be able to install the package using NuGet console.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you want, but here it is:

1. Download `nuget.exe` (∼6.5MB, no install required) from the official NuGet site: https://www.nuget.org/downloads
2. In CLI type following to retrieve list of available packages: `nuget.exe list -source <source-url-here>`
3. Then download the package by typing this: `nuget.exe install <package-name> -source <source-url-here> -OutputDirectory <download-directory>`

Contents of the downloaded package are the `.nupkg` file, `.dll` files for x86 and x64 as well as `.props` and `.targets` files. BTW: `.nupkg` can be opened as a `.zip` file.