# Install Miniprofiler without Nuget?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using `Visual Studio 2008` and I want to try `Miniprofiler`, but I don't have `Nuget`. Is it possible to install it without nuget, if so how?  I am using `Visual Studio 2008, with EF 4 and ASP.NET MVC 3`

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetSupportForVisualStudio2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. **Direct download the package**

   1. Download the nuget package by using the [direct download syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895173/51): `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{packageID}/{packageVersion}`. In this case this translates to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/MiniProfiler/3.1.1.140
   2. The nuget package can be opened through an unzip utility (or change the extension to .zip and use Windows Explorer).
   3. Extract the files, find the dll that you want to use, and use it.
2. **Build it yourself**

   1. `git clone https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet.git` or clone [the repo](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) using the GitHub UI of your choice.
   2. Open in Visual Studio, build and use