# Where is Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, web-publishing, msbuild-target

My MSBuild proj file is referencing Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets. Even though microsoft says MSBuild is standalone installation, i dont think this file is part of MSBuild. 
I am trying to setup a build server. and i don't see this file at this location. We have installed .Net 4.5.2 installed on that server.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\vXX.X\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets

After researching I found, I have to install VisualStudio to get this at that location.

Questions
Is there any way to install this Target (and other Targets at this location) without having to install visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The OP might also need the instruction how to install the package without VS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension