# How to install Nuget Package without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've been trying to install Nuget Package, as I don't use Visual Studio for some reasons, I need to do it without Visual Studio.

Is there any way?

Please help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension

Comment: I have already downloaded the file required. I failed in keeping it in right place. Any suggestions? Sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After download the NuGet package, please unzip it to local folder, which will list all content of this package. Then add the dlls in the unzipped folder into your project through Add Reference.

For example, I download EntityFramework package from nuget.org site. It will show as entityframework.6.1.3.nupkg. I unzip this .nupkg file to local folder and there has a lib folder in this unzipped folder. Then I find the EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll in that folder. I add these dlls as reference into my project.

Another way install packages without Visual Studio is using nuget.exe. Please download it from https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe

Then open command prompt windows to run nuget.exe and use the command line to install the packages that you want. The detailed command line for nuget, please refer to:

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

Comment: Doc page where the download link from the answer can be found is e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, you can install using the command:

```
winget install --source winget --id Microsoft.NuGet
```