# Binary ice.dll for .net (from zeroc) 3.7

Tags: .net, windows

I need a signed binary file ice.dll for .net (from zeroc) 3.7 - where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search reveals it on Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/zeroc.ice.net

You can follow this other stackoverflow post to install the dll:
[How to download a Nuget package without nuget.exe or Visual Studio extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension)